# "Private" TCP WCF services in Azure?

Tags: wcf, security, azure

We have three "types" applications:

1. **MainSite** (MVC Web Role, 6 instances)
2. **CoreServices** (TCP-based WCF Worker Role, 20 instances)
3. **NewFeaturesPreviewSiteOne** (MVC Web Role, 3 instances)
4. **NewFeaturesPreviewSiteTwo**
5. ...  14. **NewFeaturesPreviewSiteTwelve**

Both **MainSite** and **CoreServices** are bundled up as two roles in one deployment. This is updated ~once every 2 months. **MainSite** accesses **CoreServices** via an `InternalEndpoint` on **CoreServices**. This works great!

We now want to add **NewFeaturesPreviewSite** (in reality, we have 12 totally different/unrelated apps that you can think of like this). **NewFeaturesPreviewSite** is updated every couple days and is its own deployment. However, we **REALLY** want this to consume the already-deployed **CoreServices** app.

What is the best (or a good) way to accomplish this while considering the following?

1. Load-balancing is a must-have (20+ **CoreServices** instances handling requests from three **NewFeaturesPreviewSite** instances).
2. We do **NOT** want **CoreServices** being publicly exposed to the internet or to anything outside of our applications we're deploying to Azure.
3. I'd really like to have a solution that leverages Azure's PaaS platform rather than its IaaS platform.

Ultimately, I suspect there's something with Azure's `Local Network` or `Virtual Private Network` features that might help me here but I'm not sure - there's something about those that I don't quite get yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the public documents from Microsoft you might not be able to communicate through internal endpoints from another deployment (cloud service). This means you have to open an input endpoint on your core service for your new feature services. But I have the impression that Steve Marx had had a blog post said if you somehow know the internal endpoint, you can just connect to it from another cloud service role if both of them are located in the same data center.

Comment: Yeah, I'm also under the understanding that internal endpoints can't do this and input endpoints expose us to the internet. I'm looking for a definitive "No, you can't do this" or "this is how you're supposed to do it". I'm not looking to sniff endpoints, re-implement my own load-balancing, or anything like that. I'd rather hear "no" and wait until it becomes available than to implement it myself. However, if it's possible, I definitely want to utilize it!

Comment: As far as I know, the official answer might be 'no'.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer although I really don't know if it's correct. Signs seem to point to "No" being the answer, but I simply can't get a straight answer for this...